# Dynamic memory inside a struct

Tags: c, struct, malloc, constants

I'm editing a piece of code, that is part of a big project, that uses "const's" to initialize a bunch of arrays.
Because I want to parametrize these const's I have to adapt the code to use "malloc" in order to allocate the memory.
Unfortunately there is a problem with structs: I'm not able to allocate dynamic memory in the struct itself. Doing it outside would cause to much modification of the original code.

Here's a small example:

```
int globalx,globaly;
struct bigStruct{
    struct subStruct{
            double info1;
            double info2;
            bool valid;
    };
    double data;

    //subStruct bar[globalx][globaly];
    subStruct ** bar=(subStruct**)malloc(globalx*sizeof(subStruct*));
    for(int i=0;i<globalx;i++)
            bar[i]=(*subStruct)malloc(globaly*sizeof(subStruct));


};
int main(){
    globalx=2;
    globaly=3;
    bigStruct foo;
    for(int i=0;i<globalx;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<globaly;j++){
                    foo.bar[i][j].info1=i+j;
                    foo.bar[i][j].info2=i*j;
                    foo.bar[i][j].valid=(i==j);
            }

    return 0;
}
```

Note: in the program code I'm editing globalx and globaly were const's in a specified namespace. Now I removed the "const" so they can act as parameters that are set exactly once.

Summarized: How can I properly allocate memory for the substruct inside the struct?
Thank you very much!

Max

Comment: Are you sure this is `c++` and not `c`?

Comment: **Do not** use `malloc` or `free` on objects. The constructor and destructor will not be called. Use `new` and `delete`

Comment: That is what is called bad c++ style. Kids, never do.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion here. This was a piece of C-code inside the C++ code of the external project I'm editing.

Comment: Right now, you seem to have raw code inside a `struct`, rather than in a function.  That's neither legal nor very helpful.  Are you trying to make a declaration of a `struct bigStruct` variable call a constructor or something?  You can't do that in C.

Comment: @Yacoby, it's ok; there are no constructors/destructors in sight

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this C or C++ code.  The tags say C++ but the code looks just like C.  Why are you using `malloc` instead of `new`?

To answer your question. Give the struct a constructor to allocate the memory and a destructor to delete it.

Remember, in C++ the only difference between classes and structs is that members are private by default in a class and public by default in a struct.

Comment: You guys are right. Changing the struct into a class and using a constructor does the trick. This way I have to add minimal changes to the code.

Comment: @Maximilien, you don't even have to change it into a class.  structs can have constructors and destructors.  Just adding a constructor/destructor to your struct will work. (provided this is C++ and not C code, obviously)

Answer (score 6):

I suspect you've got little experience with C++. The logical solution is to allocate the memory in the *constructor*. It would be rather complex to start teaching C++ from that level here.

Answer (score 1):

Use constructors to do all initialization (including memory allocation), and destructors to free memory. And do not use `malloc` since you have tagged your question with `C++` tag. `malloc` is only allocates the memory, it will not initialize objects. The following sample shows how it could look in C++:

```
struct bigStruct{
    struct subStruct{
            double info1;
            double info2;
            bool valid;
    };

    // constructor
    bigStruct( size_t num_of_subs ) : bar( num_of_subs )
    {
    }
    // destructor
    ~bigStruct()
    {
    }        


protected:
    double data;    
    std::vector<subStruct> bar;
};
```

Comment: This looks good, but since I don't want to modify a lot of code I can't use vector, so I have to use a 2-dimensional array..

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function initialize_bigStruct() and use it after every definition of bigStruct. You will need to modify your code with simple find/replace.

Adding functions is not allowed in C, however if you are using C++ its a different story altogether.

Answer (score 0):

```
int globalx,globaly;
typedef struct subStruct{
        double info1;
        double info2;
        char valid;
}subStruct;
struct bigStruct{
    struct subStruct ** bar;
    double data;
};
/*Don't bother sending gl.. var since they are global*/
void alloc_struct(struct bigStruct *foo)
{
    int i;
    foo->bar=(subStruct**)malloc(globalx*sizeof(subStruct*));
    for(i=0; i<globalx; i++)
    {
        foo->bar[i]=(subStruct*)malloc(globaly*sizeof(subStruct));
    }
}
int main(){
    int i,j;
    globalx=2;
    globaly=3;
    struct bigStruct foo;
    alloc_struct(&foo);
    for(i=0;i<globalx;i++)
            for(j=0;j<globaly;j++){
                    foo.bar[i][j].info1=i+j;
                    foo.bar[i][j].info2=i*j;
                    foo.bar[i][j].valid=(i==j);
            }
    return 0;
}
```

Just a suggestion in C where you need to call a function since you cant use malloc inside a struc like you where trying to.